# How can I get many children with one title and Future

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trie to get with future the data to RadioListTile inside the ExpansionTile, but the data of futurebuilder is empty.

I took only the part of FutureBuilder and put it on top of the Card code and the api data is coming, so I believe the problem is in the ExpansionTile that is bringing the empty FutureBuilder

How can I do to get the data with Futurebuilder and put with RadioListTile into ExpansionTile?

Example:
Select the address:
o list future 1
o list future 2
o list future 3
o list future 4

```
Card(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                                child: ExpansionTile(
                                  title: Text('Calcular Frete',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        color: Colors.grey[700]
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            FutureBuilder<List<FreteModel>>(
                                                future: apiFrete.getFrete(),
                                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                                  print(snapshot.hasData);
                                                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                                                  else {
                                                    return ListView(
                                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                                        children: snapshot.data.map((f) => RadioListTile(
                                                          title: Text(f.endereco),
                                                          groupValue: radioId,
                                                          value: f.id,
                                                          onChanged: (value){
//                                                          setState(() {
                                                            radioId = value;
                                                            print(value);
//                                                          });
                                                          },
                                                        ),).toList()
                                                    );
                                                  }}),
                                          ],)
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
```

Data:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:peccatidigola/models/frete_model.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'custom_data.dart';

class FreteData {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  Future<int> _getUserID() async {
    String token;

    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = sharedPreferences.getString('token');

    var urlLoading = baseUrl + "me?token=" + token;
    var jsonResponse = null;

    var response = await http.post(urlLoading);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      return await jsonResponse['id'];
    }
  }

  Future<List<FreteModel>> getFrete() async {
    int userid = await _getUserID();

    var url = "${baseUrl}produtos/cart/frete?idUser=${userid}";

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    return decode(response);

  }

  List<FreteModel> decode(http.Response response) {

    if(response.statusCode == 200){

      var decoded = json.decode(response.body);

      List<FreteModel> categorias = decoded.map<FreteModel>(
              (map){
            return FreteModel.fromJson(map);
          }
      ).toList();

      return categorias;

    } else {

      throw Exception("Failed to load category");

    }

  }
}
```

Model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<FreteModel> freteModelFromJson(String str) => List<FreteModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => FreteModel.fromJson(x)));

class FreteModel {

  int id;
  String endereco;
  String distKm;
  int distMetros;

  FreteModel({
    this.id,
    this.endereco,
    this.distKm,
    this.distMetros,
  });

  factory FreteModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FreteModel(
    id: json["id"],
    endereco: json["endereco"],
    distKm: json["dist_km"],
    distMetros: json["dist_metros"],
  );
}
```

I call the apiFrete:

```
  FreteData apiFrete;

  FreteCart(){
    apiFrete = FreteData();
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you show apiFrete.getFrete() function? I don't see any problem with above code.

Comment: I put the model, data and how i can call the apiFrete.